# What are the different ways to know which all classes and methods present in a DLL?

Tags: c#, dll

I was in interview and interviewer asked me the below question.

`How to know what classes and methods are present in DLL ?`

I was confused and said, "we can use tool or refactor that."

Can someone explain the `different ways` to find everything from DLL (`from code as well as from tools`)

Comment: .NET Reflection: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is it a .NET dll (assembly, containing managd code) or a regular one (written in C/C++)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the interviewer was referring to reflection. For example:

```
var assembly = ...; // e.g. typeof(SomeType).Assembly
var types = assembly.GetTypes();
var methods = types.SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods());
// etc
```

You'd need to filter the types using `Type.IsClass` to get just the classes, for example. LINQ is very useful when working with reflection to query specific parts of a type or assembly. Note that the parameterless `GetMethods()` call above will only return public methods; you can specify a `BindingFlags` value to retrieve non-public methods as well.

Comment: It seems like this is the exact answer that interviewer was looking for. Thanks Jon, you are really times saver and I follow your ``pluralsight`` videos too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Get types from assembly by full path to file:

```
public IEnumerable<Type> GetAllTypesInDll(string filename)
{
    // load assembly from file
    Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(filename);

    // enumerate all types
    return asm.GetTypes();
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (Type type in from e in GetAllTypesInDll(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Console.exe"))
                      orderby e.FullName
                      select e)
{
    // print type
    Console.WriteLine("----------------");
    Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);

    // print type methods
    Console.WriteLine("Methods:");
    foreach (var mi in from e in type.GetMethods()
                       orderby e.Name
                       select e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    " + mi.Name);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("----------------");
}
```

Result:

```
----------------
<>f__AnonymousType0`7
Methods:
    Equals
    get_DisplayName
    get_EMail
    get_Groups
    get_Login
    get_Name
    get_Patronymic
    get_Surname
    GetHashCode
    GetType
    ToString
----------------
----------------
ARMUpdateService.ARMGetAllVersionsRequest
Methods:
    Equals
    GetHashCode
    GetType
    ToString
----------------
----------------
ARMUpdateService.ARMGetAllVersionsResponse
Methods:
    Equals
    GetHashCode
    GetType
    ToString
----------------
----------------
ARMUpdateService.ARMGetCurrentVersionRequest
Methods:
    Equals
    GetHashCode
    GetType
    ToString
----------------
----------------
ARMUpdateService.ARMGetCurrentVersionResponse
Methods:
    Equals
    GetHashCode
    GetType
    ToString
----------------
----------------
ARMUpdateService.ARMGetDataRequest
Methods:
    Equals
    GetHashCode
    GetType
    ToString
----------------
----------------
ARMUpdateService.ARMGetDataResponse
Methods:
    Equals
    GetHashCode
    GetType
    ToString
----------------
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides that, you can use tools such as Reflector, dotPeek or ILDASM to see content of the assembly.